MySql.EntityFrameworkCore No DbUpdateConcurrencyException thrown when concurrency conflictis expected
using MySql When the EntityFrameworkCore connects to MySQL, it does not throw the DbUpdateConcurrencyException exception when there is concurrency in updating data
Here is a snippet of my code:
  `  Services AddDbContext<testContext>（

        (sp, optionsBuilder)=>
    {
        OptionsBuilder UseMySQL (connectionString)
            . Enabling DetailedErrors ()
            . enableSensitiveDataLogging();
    });


    [Table("user_count2")]
    Public class UserAccount
    {
        [Column("id")]
        Public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("user_id")]
        Public int? UserId { get; set; }


        [StringLength(11)]
        //[Comment ("Account Name")]
        [Column("account name")]
        Public string AccountName { get; set; }



        //[Comment ("Creation Time")]
        [Column("create-time")]
        Public DateTime? Create Time { get; set; }

        [Column("is_delete")]
        Public int? IsDelete { get; set; }

        [Column("delete-time")]
        Public DateTime? DeleteTime {get; set;}

        [Column("version", TypeName = "varchar")]
    //[Timestamp]
        [ConcurrencyCheck]
    //[Timestamp]
        Public Guid Version {get; set;}

        [Column(name: "createat", TypeName = "timestamp")]
        Public DateTime? Create At {get; set;}
    }
    UserAccount? UserAccount = testContext UserAccounts Find (100003);
    //Console WriteLine (userAccount. CreateAt?. ToString ("yyyy MM dd HH: mm: ss. fff: ffffff"));
    Try
    {
        UserAccount AccountName="atest";
        UserAccount Version = Guid NewGuid();
        UserAccount Create At=DateTime UtcNow;
        TestContext UserAccounts Update (userAccount);
        Int rows = testContext SaveChanges ();
        Console WriteLine(rows);
    }
    Catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {

        Throw ex;
    }`

The execution result always returns 1, and no DbUpdateConcurrencyException exception was thrown
Thanks in advance for your help !
